# Android - Socket NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to send a image from client to server , when I start sending , server stuck at

```
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ois);
```

and after I kill the client activity LogCat show this

```
03-28 17:59:41.102: D/skia(12173): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null 
 03-28 17:59:41.102: D/ReceiveImage(12173): After BitmapFactory
 03-28 17:59:41.112: D/runOnUiThread(12173): Setting Image 
 03-28 17:59:41.142: E/initTCPServer(12173): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

**EDIT:**

Server code :

```
    public void ReceiveImage(){
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(3000);
        Socket clientmessage = serverSocket.accept();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientmessage.getInputStream());
        //Object ImageObject = ois.readObject();            
        //ois.read(image);
        Log.d("ReceiveImage", "Befor BitmapFactory");
        byte[] compressedBitmap = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(compressedBitmap, 0, compressedBitmap.length);
        //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(clientmessage.getInputStream());
        Log.d("ReceiveImage", "After BitmapFactory");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("runOnUiThread", "Setting Image");
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientmessage.getOutputStream());
        oos.writeObject("Received");
        ois.close();
        oos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("initTCPServer", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Client code :

```
    public void SendImage(){
    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(ServerIP, 3000);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.lena);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] compressedImage = baos.toByteArray();
        oos.writeObject(compressedImage);
        oos.flush();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        String respond = (String)ois.readObject();
        Log.d("ObjectInputStream", respond);            
        oos.close();
        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SendImage", e.toString());
    }

}
```

> 03-30 15:59:22.013: E/SendImage(18664): java.lang.NullPointerException

What I'm doing wrong?
(Image size : 10KB)

Comment: Have you tried using a FlushedInputStream? Check out this thread: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revise Clinet code like this

```
    public void SendImage(){
    try {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ServerIP);
        clientSocket = new Socket(address, 3000);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.image);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] compressedImage = baos.toByteArray();
        oos.writeObject(compressedImage);
        oos.flush();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        String respond = (String)ois.readObject();
        Log.d("ObjectInputStream", respond);            
        oos.close();
        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SendImage", e.toString());
    }
    
}
```

it works !

Answer (score 1):

You should serialize the image before sending it to `ObjectOutputStream`, which is expected to handle serializable objects.

Try to use bitmap.compress (with a `ByteArrayOutputStream`) then send the byte array to the server, and ois should return a byte array that imageFactory should be able to decode.

**edited to follow the edited code:**
You must send your object with writeObject rather than write, then on the receive end you will get a byte array:

Client:

```
byte[] compressedImage = baos.toByteArray();
oos.writeObject(compressedImage);
```

Server:

```
byte[] compressedBitmap = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(compressedBitmap, 0, compressedBitmap.length);
```

Comment: I revised my answer ;)

Comment: I revised my code like you suggested and I'm so sorry , I didn't check clinet LogCat , it has an exception , maybe was the exception cause server stuck .

Comment: I use java try to do same thing , it's work , why android got exception ?

Answer (score -2):

You should use `BitmapDescriptorFactory` instead of `BitmapFactory`.

Comment: Should I import some package? I can't use BitmapDescriptorFactory

Answer (score -2):

You should import this class:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
```